# HTML replacing a specific content on the screen without changing the content around it

Tags: html, jquery

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#content1").load("src/screens/content1.html");
            $("#content2").load("src/screens/content2.html");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="layout1">
        some kind of button
    </div>
    <div class="layout2">
        <div id="content1"></div> //when button is click, content1 is replace by content2 on the same page
    </div>
</body>
```

How can I create a dynamic page, where when I click a button at the top of the screen the content in the middle of the page will change?
So let say the current page is displaying content1 in the middle of the screen, without changing anything else on the page, this button will replace content1 with content2 while keeping other content on the page the same.

Right now I'm displaying the content with

```
<div id="content1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already written have of the solution.
Just wire up the button clicks to the functions responsible for loading the required content.

I changed your HTML a little bit to suit the javascript code I added.

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".layout1").click(function(){
                $("#content").load("src/screens/content1.html"); 
            });
            $(".layout2").click(function(){
               $("#content").load("src/screens/content2.html");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="layout1">Click to Load Content 1</div>
    <div class="layout2">Click to Load Content 2</div>

    <div id="content"></div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank You.